# Do proper dense subgroups of the real numbers have uncountable index

Tags: real-analysis, abstract-algebra, group-theory, axiom-of-choice

Just what it says on the tin.  Let $G$ be a dense subgroup of $\mathbb{R}$; assume that $G \neq \mathbb{R}$.  I know that the index of $G$ in $\mathbb{R}$ has to be infinite (since any subgroup of $\mathbb{C}$ of finite index in $\mathbb{C}$ has to have index 1 or 2); does it have to be uncountable, though?  All the examples I can readily come up with (e.g. $\mathbb{Q}$, $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{2}]$, ...) have uncountable index in $\mathbb{R}$.

Thanks!

Comment: I think this should work: Let $(\xi_i)$ be a basis for $\mathbb R$ as a vector space over $\mathbb Q$. Now what happens when you remove one element from the set of $\xi_i$?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No: $\mathbb{R}$ is a $\mathbb{Q}$-vector space. Choose a basis and drop finitely many basis elements to find a $\mathbb{Q}$-subspace $G$ of finite codimension. Clearly, $G$ has countable index in $\mathbb{R}$ and is dense.

**Added:** It can't be done without some form of the axiom of choice. The statement $\mathbb{R} \cong \mathbb{R} \oplus \mathbb{Q}$ is form number 252 in the book [Consequences of the Axiom of Choice](http://books.google.com/books?id=YXaVkHPQED4C), by Howard and Rubin, as you can check on [the homepage](http://consequences.emich.edu/CONSEQ.HTM) of the book.

C. J. Ash explains in [A consequence of the axiom of choice](http://dx.doi.org/10.1017/S1446788700031505), Journal of the Australian Mathematical Society (Series A), 19 (1975) 306-308, that $\mathbb{R} \cong \mathbb{R} \oplus \mathbb{Q}$ implies the existence of non-measurable sets in $\mathbb{R}$. This in turn is known not to be provable from ZF alone.

If you want to know more about this, you can consult Herrlich, [The Axiom of Choice](http://books.google.com/books?id=JXIiGGmq4ZAC), chapter 5, especially [the pages following Diagram 5.10](http://books.google.com/books?id=JXIiGGmq4ZAC&pg=PA122).

Comment: Great; thanks!  One more question: can this be done *constructively* (that is, w/o axiom of choice)?

Comment: I feared that this follow-up question would come :-) See edit.

Comment: Excellent; this is all exactly what I wanted to know (and pretty much what I expected, but I really appreciate having the references). Thanks again!