# Dense uncountable proper subgroup of $(\mathbb{R},+)$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, group-theory

Probably someone had asked this question on StackExchange, but can one construct a dense uncountable proper subgroup of $(\mathbb{R},+)$?

Comment: Good question! I don't think the density requirement is really needed. A related question: is it still true if we replace "subgroup" with "subfield"?

Comment: I think an answer can be found by studying http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/421309/do-proper-dense-subgroups-of-the-real-numbers-have-uncountable-index

Comment: Thanks Gerry, so it's not obvious if we don't assume AC...

Comment: If a subgroup of $(\mathbb{R},+)$ is uncountable, it is automatically dense.

Comment: See also [this question](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/35970/construction-of-a-proper-uncountable-subgroup-of-mathbbr-without-choice) from MO

Comment: @Hsueh-YungLin Mikko Korhonen's link and Daniel Fischer's comment resolves the problem in ZF. You could wrap them up and answer your own question?

Comment: [This StackExchange question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/285454/are-mathbbr-and-mathbbq-the-only-nontrivial-subfields-of-mathbbr) might also be of interest.

Answer (score 8):

Here's one from Hardy's "A course of pure math":

$\displaystyle \{x \in \mathbb{R}: \lim_{n \to \infty} \sin(n! \pi x) = 0\}$.

Comment: What kind of $x$ does this include outside of rationals?

Comment: @hot_queen: Could you please give a more precise reference (Edition, Chapter, page perhaps)?  Hardy shows there that this set is uncountable?

Comment: You can read about it here: http://www.math.wisc.edu/~akumar/BOREL_GROUPS.pdf

Comment: Thanks hot_queen.  Good example, but it seems a little misleading to say it is from Hardy, at least from the reference given in your link, where the question of what numbers beyond rationals are in the set isn't addressed.  Maybe later in the book?

Comment: You are right. As far as I remember, Hardy did't consider the question of what reals are in this set beyond the rationals.

Answer (score 5):

Quoting an [answer of François Dorais](https://mathoverflow.net/a/35974/) on Mathoverflow:

> This [earlier answer of mine](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/23202/explicit-big-linearly-independent-sets/23206#23206) shows how to get an uncountable $\mathbb{Q}$-independent subset of $\mathbb{R}$ in ZF. This set is not a Hamel basis so the $\mathbb{Q}$-span of this set is as required.