# Proving $(\Bbb R,+)$ has no proper subgroup isomorphic to itself

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-isomorphism

A captioned image with the text "*My love for you is like a group which has a proper subgroup isomorphic to itself*" was recently posted in a group chat I'm in.  Ignoring the argument about the semantics of the language used (*I am of the firm opinion that "itself" is in reference to the parent group, not the subgroup*) this got me wondering about examples of groups which have this property.  That is to say, a group $G$ that has a proper subgroup $H$ such that $G$ is isomorphic to $H$.

A few examples came to mind such as $(\Bbb Z,+) > (2\Bbb Z,+)$ and $(\Bbb Q^*,\times) > (K,\times)$ where $K=\{\frac{a}{b}~:~a,b\in\Bbb Z\setminus\{0\},~\gcd(a,2)=\gcd(b,2)=1\}$ and similar.  (*Note: subgroup, not subring*)

I got to thinking about $(\Bbb R,+)$ however and wondering whether or not the real numbers have a subgroup isomorphic to the reals with respect to addition.  My gut feeling is no, but I am at a loss as to how to prove this or come up with an example.  Proper subgroups certainly exist, such as how $(\Bbb Q,+)<(\overline{\Bbb Q},+)<(\Bbb R,+)$, and so by specifying that our proper subgroup $H$ doesn't contain some element $x$, be it rational or irrational, that doesn't preclude $H$ from existing.

So then, I ask you, does $(\Bbb R,+)$ have a proper subgroup isomorphic to $(\Bbb R,+)$?  How does one prove it doesn't (*if it doesn't*)?  Does it even have a proper subgroup which is uncountable?  (*All examples I can think of are countable*)

Comment: For the record, $\displaystyle \{x \in \mathbb{R}: \lim_{n \to \infty} \sin(n! \pi x) = 0\}$ is a dense subgroup of $\mathbb{R}$ which is uncountable. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/494366/dense-uncountable-proper-subgroup-of-mathbbr?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: A group $G$ which contains no proper subgroup $H< G$ with $H\cong G$ is called *coHopfian* (so you are looking for non-coHopfian groups). For example, a group which splits as a free-product is non-coHopfian. A massive result of Sela from '97 (*Structure and Rigidity in (Gromov) Hyperbolic Groups and Discrete Groups in Rank 1 Lie Groups II*, GAFA, [MR1466338](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1466338)) was that a torsion-free hyperbolic group is coHopfian if and only if it does not split as a free product. Reinfeldt-Weidmann (preprint) have proven this for all hyperbolic groups.

Comment: Then "almost every" finitely presented group is coHopfian, so your examples are few and far between: There is a formal definition, due essentially to Gromov, of a "random" group, and these groups are all torsion-free hyperbolic, and hence coHopfian by Sela's result. These papers are hard. A more readable, and mostly self-contained proof that "almost all" groups are coHopfian in Kapovich, Schupp, *Genericity, the Arzhantseva-Olʹshanskii method and the isomorphism problem for one-relator groups*, Math. Ann. (2005) [MR2107437](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=2107437).

Comment: (The other take-home point is that people *care* about this property - Sela's paper was in GAFA which is a highly prestigious journal, and Sela is a big shot. The Kapovich-Schupp paper was in Mathematische Annalen, one of the big, classic journals. Einstein used to be an editor of Mathematische Annalen.)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is if you accept AC.

$\Bbb R$ is a vector space over $\Bbb Q$, so has a vector space
basis (*Hamel basis*) as a vector space over $\Bbb Q$. Removing a generator,
the remaining generators generate a proper $\Bbb Q$-subspace isomorphic to $\Bbb R$
as a vector space, and so as an Abelian group.

Comment: Might as well mention here that (assuming AC) $(\mathbb R,+)$ is isomorphic to $(\mathbb C,+)$ as well as (obviously) to a proper subgroup of $(\mathbb C,+)$.

Answer (score 6):

Consider $\mathbb{R}$ as a vector space over the rationals and some 
basis $B$. Then $B$ is Infinite. Let $b\in B$. Then there is a bijection between $B$ and $B':=B\setminus\{b\}$ implying that the vector spaces generated by $B$ and $B'$ are isomorphic. Thus they are also isomorphic as abelian groups. Finally note that the space generated by $B'$ is strictly contained in the space generated by $B$ which is $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: When writing the answer I was uns wäre of the answer by Lord Shark the Unknown.

Comment: Here "uns wäre" is "unaware" and "Lord Shark the Unknown" is "Angina Seng".